# How are GET values passed to a URL given only a path and no page

Tags: php, get

I am writing a PHP script (MyPHPScript) that takes a URL and downloads that URL (called TargetURL) via `file_get_contents`. The script then rewrites all anchors `<a>` and all form actions (`action=""`) so that they point back to MyPHPScript.

MyPHPScript may come across a form as follows:

```
<form name="MYFORM" method="GET" action="http://www.TargetURL.com/index.php">
    <input type="input" name="Username"/>
```

and would rewrite this as follows:

```
<form name="MYFORM" method="GET" action="MyPHPScript.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="OriginalAction" value="http://www.TargetURL.com/index.php"/>
    <input type="input" name="Username"/>
</form>
```

After all processing, MyPHPScript then outputs the modified code of TargetURL. If I then submit this form, MyPHPScript checks for a `GET` value of `OriginalAction` and downloads that URL passing all relevant `GET` values along with it.

This works fine, however one particular form on a TargetURL is as follows:

```
<form name="MYFORM" method="GET" action="http://www.TargetURL.com/search/">
    <input type="input" name="SearchTerm"/>
```

MyPHPScript rewrites this as follows:

```
<form name="MYFORM" method="GET" action="MyPHPScript.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="OriginalAction" value="http://www.TargetURL.com/search/"/>
    <input type="input" name="SearchTerm"/>
```

The issue being is that when I submit this form, MYPHPScript attemps to download the URL

```
http://www.TargetURL.com/search/?SearchTerm=XYZ
```

However, this is not working. As I do not control TargetURL.com, I can only guess why, but I get the error message that there are no search results indicating it is not passing the GET properly. So, how do I pass GET values to a URI when there is no filename present, or is the above URI valid and TargetURL.com is possibly doing something special?

Comment: @hakre, ack, my apologies.... Seems I had not copied the last characters of that line properly. :)

Comment: I've changed the question to make it a little clearer, but targetpage is the page I am fetching (i.e. the one I do not control).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?... can you give an example?

Comment: Okay, now that this is clear: The browser uses the `action` value and resolves it to the documents base-URI. From the code you've given, it is not clear why it resolves it to `http://www.otherserver.com/search/` it should have resolved it to `http://yourserver/path/to/MyPHPPage.php`.

Comment: @hakre, my apologies - I think I may have explained it badly as I think you have the wrong end of the stick... I'll have a think about how I can reword the question to be clearer.

Comment: You could elaborate what you mean by *"page is not known"* as the page is always known.

Comment: From what I see, this should work. The url your page is resolving seems correct, unless 1) there is referral checking of some sort, 2) the url is incorrect. What are the contents of the fetched page?

Comment: Question text update... I hope this is a little clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the GET values like that is perfectly valid, however it seems that the site is doing something clever with a bit of javascript to stop these sort of rewrites. How I don't have a clue. my apologies for the inconvenience.